How to dynamically get the class type in a generic custom repository implementation in Spring Data JDBC?
I am working with Spring Data JDBC and have implemented a custom repository with generic types. I need to dynamically get the class type in my custom repository implementation to form dynamic queries. I can only use spring data jdbc(can't use JPA)
Here is my implementation
@Slf4j
public class CrudRepositoryCustomImpl\<T, ID\> implements CrudRepositoryCustom\<T, ID\> {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public CrudRepositoryCustomImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        String tableName = ""; // Need to dynamically get table name based on T
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE IS_DELETED = FALSE LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("limit", pageable.getPageSize());
        parameters.addValue("offset", pageable.getOffset());
    
        List<Object> results = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Object.class));
        String countSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE IS_DELETED = FALSE";
        Long total = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(countSql, parameters, Long.class);
    
        return new PageImpl<T>((List<T>) results, pageable, total);
    }

}

I have an interface for my custom repository:
public interface CrudRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}

And a repository interface that extends this custom repository:
public interface MilestoneRepository extends CrudRepositoryCustom<Milestone, Long> {
}

My goal is to dynamically determine the table name based on the class type T. How can I achieve this in my CrudRepositoryCustomImpl class? or How to override CrudRepository Method to my CustomRepository.

"My goal is to dynamically determine the table name based on the class type T" is not clear to me - The table name is the class name, expect you define your own name (using @Table (name="tablename") annotation on class level, namly class T)

sorry im not good at english. I just want determine generic type on
public interface MilestoneRepository extends CrudRepositoryCustom<Milestone, Long> {
}
``` like this code
